# Photorec found less files than before even though sd card hasn't been written to at all

Tags: file-recovery

The first time I ran it, it found 50 flac files. Now it found only 47.
**Why is this?**

I had to run it again because I accidentally pressed shift+delete when selecting flac files with the shift key...I've immediately tried Photorec to restore the accidentally deleted flac files. But to my surprise it didn't find anything and all other programs failed too.

**So why the files cant be recovered *immediately after deleting* them?**

UPDATE: many of the flac files are 0bytes even though last time they weren't.

Comment: Maybe I can find all 66 flac files by setting a different offset etc in options?? But no satisfactory seacrh results for this either

Comment: THIS LIKELY isnt flac file specific

Comment: And what makes you believe that it hasn't been written to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Photorec I assume there are some problems with the SD card. And with failing storage devices:

> Every byte read may be the last byte that you ever get from the device.

(this isn't my wording, but can't find the source). So perhaps the SD card is gradually failing and there is nothing you can do about it. Perhaps you should be careful around the delete key when recovering files. But even with shift+delete, there should be a confirmation dialog!?